# Channel not showing in Slave node - Redis Sentinel

Tags: server, redis, redis-sentinel

I have created a Redis Sentinel with 1 master and 2 slave nodes. I executed a java program but when I stop the redis in master, it wasn't creating a channel. When I looked into it, the channel name is only available in the master node and not in the slave nodes.

[master_node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qaj4.png)

[slave_node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46twJ.png)

As you can see, the channel "clustering" is not in the slave node. Do I have to update anything in the configuration file?

I checked all the internet and found nothig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channels are not replicated to slaves in that sense. The `clustering` channel shown when doing `pubsub channels` on the master means that there are subscribers to that channel.

`pubsub channels` from the documentation:

> Lists the currently active channels.
>
> An active channel is a Pub/Sub channel with one or more subscribers (excluding clients subscribed to patterns).

In the event of an failover, many client libraries will handle all this automatically as soon as Sentinel has promoted a new master. That means that the client get a new master node and can auto subscribe to previous subscribed channels.

Note that there are often special connection properties in the client library for using Sentinel.